# How to know if fragment has been recreated

Tags: android

I need to display some data in ListFragment. I'm downloading data from internet with AsyncTask and then update data with Adapter.

```
public void onActivityCreated(Bundle savedInstanceState) {

    super.onActivityCreated(savedInstanceState);
    activity = getActivity();
    context = activity.getApplicationContext();
    res = activity.getResources();
    resFactory = createFactory(context);
    dataFolder = resFactory.getDataFolder();
    dataFile = resFactory.getDataFile();
    ArrayList list = resFactory.getArrayList();
    setListAdapter(resFactory.getAdapter(context, list));
    linkToData = resFactory.getDataLink(res);
    getData();

}
```

in `getData` I'm starting `AsyncTask`.

I want `getData` to be executed only once inside one user session. So if fragment was detached and then attached again, I don't want to download data again. But if fragment was just created I want it to download data.

The simple answer to that would be call `getData` from `onCreate()`, but then I get nullPointer, because at that point I have no `AsyncTask`. So I need to somehow to know whether fragment was just have been created or it was just detached and then attached again.

English is not my native language. So I'm sorry If my question is not very understandable.

Comment: After loading them data saved it in some other class as a static collection, when ever you come to that fragment first check the data is there or not otherwise just load it.

Comment: My data is saved in files (xml, json and jpeg thumbnails).
If I would just check whether this files exists then when my app would be lauched more then once it wouldn't update the data, because files would exists. And I want my app to update data with every launch if it is possible. So it's not a solution to my problem.

Comment: It's not a solution to my problem, because data it stored beetween user sessions. So when app would start for a second time data would exists in xml, json and jpeg files and wouldn't be updated.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

```
package com.example.gridview;

import android.os.Bundle;
import android.support.v4.app.Fragment;

/**
 * @author rajeshcp
 */
public class FrgamentX extends Fragment {

    private boolean mIsCreated;



    @Override
    public void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        // TODO Auto-generated method stub
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
    }



    @Override
    public void onResume() {
        // TODO Auto-generated method stub
        super.onResume();
        if(!mIsCreated)
        {
                    mIsCreated = true;
            //load data
        }
    }
}
```

This is also will work.